# C++ Class Composition error: unrefined reference

Tags: c++, class, abstract-class

Having this annoying error.

I keep getting undefined reference to class::method

This is the code that I'd like to do

```
student::student(){
conscience* c;
unsigned short choice = rand() % 4;
if (choice == 0){
    c = new betray();
}
if (choice == 1){
    c = new silent();
}
if (choice == 2){
    c = new confused();
}
if (choice == 3){
    c = new experienced();
}
```

but I keep getting the error.

This work around works nicely but is not in the main classes constructor but passed by arguments

```
student::student(conscience* c){
    m_Conscience = c;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Exact error: undefined reference to `betray::betray()'

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: The words are "silent" and "experienced" by the way. As someone who has had to maintain code that has variables and functions declared (and used) with typos in them, I implore you to fix those two now, before they cause too many headaches.

Comment: Also, there's not enough code here to know what's going on. What is that workaround even replacing?

Comment: From seeing this error 69001 times, you probably forgot a `className::` on one of your definitions, or forgot to define it altogether. To narrow it down, it's whichever of the four there is included in the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined reference can mean one of the following:

1. You have a method declaration in a base class, which you call but is never implemented in any derived class.
2. Or, it is implemented, but you are not linking to it, so the linker can't find it.

I suggest you check if you are linking against betray.o. Check your makefile. If you don't have a makefile, I encourage you to write one.

Comment: Thanks so much. Completely forgot about fixing the base class.